# Sqlite optional param

Tags: sql, sqlite

How to write something like this in SQLite ? Like optional param if null don't use.

```
(@Year IS NULL OR @Year = DATEPART(year, Date)
```

Comment: Sorry, but doesn't this code actually work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
IFNULL(@Year, DATEPART(year, Date)) = DATEPART(year, Date)
```

[IFNULL](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html) returns its first non-null argument. In this case, the query will compare `@Year` to `DATEPART(year, Date)` as long as `@Year` is not null. If it IS null, then it'll compare `DATEPART(year, Date)` to `DATEPART(year, Date)`, which will always be true.

**Edit:** Note that `DATEPART` is not a native SQLite method (the OP referenced it so it may be a custom thing he/she is using). A native solution is to use `strftime("%Y", Date)` (Thanks @Jason!)

Comment: DatePart is not an SQLite function?

Comment: @Jason Hm, so it isn't. I was just using the same method that the OP used -- it might be something he wrote for himself.

Comment: @ean5533 Fair enough. Perhaps for those of us who don't have the function but have the same problem we could use strftime("%Y", Date). Could you add that to your answer :) ?